# Converting latin1 database to utf-8

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database that has `latin1` tables. I need to convert every column, table, etc. to utf-8. Specifically:

```
Encoding: UTF-8
Collation: utf8_general_ci (or utf-8's default)
```

What would be the quickest way to make these sweeping changes to my database?

Comment: How many rows has its tables?

Comment: It is possible to do with `alter table`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: very nice point! More reading: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqldump`, then edit your dump, replacing encoding specifiers for your tables and columns (and preserving your dump encoding in header `SET NAMES` command), then `mysql` back.

Comment: What do you need `iconv` for?

Comment: to convert the data latin1 to UTF-8. I suppose that initial data encoding is specified correctly.

Comment: if the initial data encoding is correct and data isn't broken - you don't need to convert it. Just change encoding in table definitions and mysql will do the left. Current encoding of the dump only affects the client (connection) encoding. So you can have the dump in any encoding you want. And performing `iconv` likely will break everything for OP ;-)